# Is this an acceptable usage of UUID or GUID?

Tags: uuid, guid, uniqueidentifier

I'm making a class that takes an object and assigns it an ID number that's unique. It's nothing special, it takes the object, assigns a number to it, and then increments the ID counter for the next object that will receive an ID number.

I want to call the member UUID, or GUID, standing for Universally unique identifier, or Globally unique identifier, because this language is very clear for what the member is.

However I looked up the term and Wikipedia says:

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128-bit number used to
>   identify information in computer systems.
>   [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Which makes me think the terms have a very specific meaning, and that possibly my use of it to just mean a unique number given to each object is not proper usage. I'm thinking of using 32-bit int or the like.

Is this an incorrect use of UUID or GUID? I don't think it matters, but I'm writing in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it would be a misuse of those terms. The word *universally* in UUID or *globally* in GUID means that the identifier is not only unique within your specific system, but within *any* system developed for any purpose, anywhere. A 32-bit integer that you simply increment for each new entity doesn't have that property. It may be unique within your system, but not universally. I would just call it `Identifier` or something similar.

Comment: When you say 'within any system developed for any purpose anywhere", do you mean that a Beijing hospital's UUID of a patient should be different from a Los Angeles law firm's UUID of a client?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Collision (i.e., two systems generating the same UUID) isn't impossible, but given correct implementation, the probability is so small as to be negligible for most purposes. Details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions

Answer (score 1):

You will find your answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateguid). in c++ you have a method for creating guid:

```
GUID gidReference;
HRESULT hCreateGuid = CoCreateGuid( &gidReference );
```

what it means is:

> The CoCreateGuid function calls the RPC function [UuidCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate), which
>   creates a GUID, a globally unique 128-bit integer. Use CoCreateGuid
>   when you need an absolutely unique number that you will use as a
>   persistent identifier in a distributed environment.To a very high
>   degree of certainty, this function returns a unique value – no other
>   invocation, on the same or any other system (networked or not), should
>   return the same value.

and when we dive in we see:

> For security reasons, it is often desirable to keep ethernet addresses
>   on networks from becoming available outside a company or organization.
>   The UuidCreate function generates a UUID that cannot be traced to the
>   ethernet address of the computer on which it was generated. It also
>   cannot be associated with other UUIDs created on the same computer. If
>   you do not need this level of security, your application can use the
>   UuidCreateSequential function, which behaves exactly as the UuidCreate
>   function does on all other versions of the operating system.

I dim it important so you will not only know that you misused it, but also that you will know why, because in future days this information may be of important value to you.